# python: is it possible to sort a dictionary by key?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

A previous stack overflow question on sorting a dictionary by key suggested the following for python 3.6+:

```
d={2:3,1:89,4:5,3:0}
b=dict(sorted(d.items()))
print(b)
```

And as expected the output is as follows:

```
{1: 89, 2: 3, 3: 0, 4: 5}
```

However when I enter the following

```
a={'1':1,'x':4,'z':-40023,'c':234}
c=dict(sorted(d.items()))
print(c)
```

This is the output produced: 
`{'1': 1, 'c': 234, 'x': 4, 'z': -40023`}

My questions are as follows:

1. Why does this approach work for the first case and not the second.
2. Why does it only work for python3.6+ and not before. Did they change the implementation of the dictionary class?
3. Is b in the above code a new sorted dictionary and if so how is that possible as I learned that hashtables are never ordered?

Comment: dict insert ordering is not a thing prior to Python 3.6+ - don’t rely on it in code if this cannot be guaranteed. See OrderedDict otherwise, which exists in all relevant Python versions.

Comment: `'1', 'c', 'x', 'z'` is the correct ordering

Comment: 3) Because of little white lies that (ignore specific implementation details/quirks/features and) make it easier to talk about universal ADTs like “Map”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The second example is sorted correctly. See the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to verify that digits come before letters.
2. Python 3.6 (specifically the CPython implementation) [changed the way dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation) are implemented. A side effect of this change is that dictionaries retain the element insertion order, which can be very handy. This was just a side effect in 3.6, but the [BDFL decreed](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html) that this change be made a feature of the language beginning with version 3.7.
3. `b` in your code above is indeed a new `dict`, and based on item 2 above, insertion order is retained. In this case, items are inserted in sorted order.